# Java read byte array from PostgreSQL and write to image file

Tags: java, postgresql, image, fileoutputstream, bytea

I need to read an image byte array from a PostgreSQL table which is done as

```
byte[] fileBytes = resultsSet.getBytes(1);
```

When I try to write it to a image file, it does not open (unsupported file type). The following is the code

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\test.png"); 
fos.write(fileBytes);
fos.close();
```

Comment: `"D:\\test.png"` with doubled backslash; you wrote a tab+"est.png"

Comment: @JoopEggen Sorry that was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method, worked for me:

```
      InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(rs.getBytes(1));
      BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);
                    if(null == bImageFromConvert){
                        throw new Exception("Invalid image");
                    }
                    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("e:/images/"+"test".jpg");

        ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "png", out);
```

Comment: I am getting `invalid image` exception even though `in ` is not null. When I am trying to call `ImageIO.read()` it returns `null`.

Comment: Hey, have you come across a solution?

Comment: Not yet, please let me know if you have any other suggestion.